# Python refactoring with thread and queue

Tags: python, multithreading

I was trying to restructure my code,first version is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419209/parsing-python-queue-object)

What I want is to run two objects concurrently

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from html.parser import HTMLParser
import urllib.request

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 3

HOSTS = ["http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://ibm.com"]


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("Start tag:", tag)
        for attr in attrs:
            print("\tattr:", attr)


class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        super(ProducerThread, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

        def run(self):
            while True:
                for host in HOSTS:
                    url = urllib.request.urlopen(host)
                    content = str(url.read(4096))                    
                    queue.put(content)


class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,queue):
        super(ConsumerThread, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue


        def run(self):
            while True:
                item = queue.get()
                parser = MyHTMLParser()
                new_con = parser.feed(item)
                print(new_con)
                queue.task_done()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()

    p = ProducerThread(queue)
    c = ConsumerThread(queue)
    p.start()
    c.start()
```

When I run code from terminal there is no output.What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unindent the `run` methods so that they are not inside the `__init__` methods.

Note however you almost certainly don't want those to loop forever; remove the `while True`.